# Libgdx fbx converter doesn't write meshes to g3dj file

Tags: libgdx, blender, fbx

LibGDX FBX converter doesn't write meshes nor materials to g3dj file.

This happens with blender 2.8 when exporting model to `FBX` then converting it to `g3dj`. meshes will result in an empty block.

2.8 blender settings

[image]

and when converting...

[image]

`g3dj` file..

```
{
   "version": [  0,   1], 
   "id": "", 
   "meshes": [], 
   "materials": [], 
   "nodes": [
       {
           "id": "Cube", 
           "rotation": [-0.707107, -0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
           "scale": [ 10.000000,  10.000000,  10.000000]
       }
   ], 
   "animations": []
}
```

I tried to convert a `fbx` written with blender `2.76` with these settings...

[image]

and meshes and materials are written in `g3dj` file successfully. I'm thinking this has to do with `FBX` version, but it seems you can't change `FBX` version in blender `2.8`

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, IT says  the error right on the terminal

`skipping geometry without materials`

Just add a material to the model.

Seems blender previous versións of blender models comes with a default material